# Null Pointer Exception while running servlet in browser

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I want to display all cookies stored on browser but getting null pointer exception

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class DisplayCookie extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws     IOException,ServletException{

    Cookie[] c=req.getCookies();
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    int i=0;
    while(i  < c.length){
        String cname=c[i].getName();
        String cvalue=c[i].getValue();
        pw.println("name="+cname+" ;value="+cvalue);
        i++;
        }
    pw.close();
    }
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

I am getting stack trace like this.

```
 HTTP Status 500 -
 type Exception report message
 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

DisplayCookie.doGet(DisplayCookie.java:14)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Seems req.getCookies(); returning null; perform NOT null check before getting elements from c.

Comment: Which line of your code throwing exception?? can u post the error data

Comment: @user2503916 it's no rocket science to spot which variable will be `null`.

Comment: Please look at the indicated line 14th and think about which variable could, improperly, be NULL at this point. Think about why it happened to be null. Then you'll arrive at the point where you have a concrete problem to diagnose and where you can start thinking about who/why gave you that null instead of an object. That might be a good question, not how it stands now. You didn't even marked in your code which line is the 14th. Someone already pinpointed the problem for you, but please do what I suggest as an excercise!

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29)

> Returns:
>   an array of all the Cookies included with this request, or **null** if the request has no cookies

Enclose the `while` loop in with a guard statement check:

```
if (c != null) {
   while(i<c.length) {
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: When i using if loop as u said i m getting out of if loop.I think if condition is not satisfying..so what should i do??

Comment: Is this a compilation or runtime error? If it is a compilation error check that youre enclosing the `while` statement block correctly

Comment: It is a runtime error.  The error line is the while loop line from above code   .. What actually i want to do is  i have make a html page called "addcookie.html" where i have inserted a cookie data and executed a servlet to save that cookie to browser called "setcookie.java" and on third servlet that i have shown here called "Displaycooke.java" i want to display all cookies from browser.